# How can I access an "aws_ami" Id which I retrieved through a "data" resource in another module in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So first of all let me try to give you an overview of my project structure:

[image: -parent -main -outputs -variables -tfvars -modules -gitlab(again with outputs, main and variables)<-data ami -monitoring(again with outputs, main and variables)<-needed]

I set up "Cloudwatch Alarms" in my module "monitoring", all working fine but because I use metrics of the CloudWatch Agent I have to declare the "image_id" of the instances I want to monitor.

The ami of this "image_id" is located in my module "gitlab". I retrieved the ami object through a data resource like this:

```
data "aws_ami" "ami_img" {
    most_recent = true
    owners = ["326578563245"]
    }
}
```

After this i put it in the outputs of the module gitlab like this:

```
output "ami" {
  value = data.aws_ami.ami_img
}
```

Now I put it in the main.tf of the parent like this:

```
module "monitoring" {
  ami_img_id = module.monitoring.ami.id
}
```

After that i initialized the variable in the variables.tf of the module "monitoring" like this:

```
variable "ami_img_id" {}
```

So now I should be able to use its attributes in the main.tf of my module "monitoring" like this:

```
#Alarm for Drive: 90% Maximum 1/1 Datapoint Period 30 Minutes
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "disk_used" {
  alarm_name                = "${var.env_prefix}|Gitlab|Disk used > 90%!"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "1"
  metric_name               = "disk_used_percent"
  namespace                 = "CWAgent"
  period                    = "1800"
  statistic                 = "Maximum"
  threshold                 = "90"
  datapoints_to_alarm       = "1"
  alarm_description         = "This alarm is triggered if 1/1 Datapoint, in 30 Minutes, is over 90%."
  #alarm_actions             = aws_sns_topic.topic_alarms.arn
  alarm_actions        = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.topic_alarms_data.arn}"]
  dimensions                = {
  InstanceId                = data.aws_instance.gitlab_data.instance_id
  ImageId                   = var.ami_img_id
  InstanceType             = data.aws_instance.gitlab_data.instance_type
  device                    = "xvda1"
  fstype                    = "xfs"
  path                      = "/"
  }
  insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

When I try to

```
terraform apply
```

I get this output:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 68, in module "monitoring":
│   68:   ami_img_id = module.monitoring.ami.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.monitoring is a object, known only after apply
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "ami".
```

I already applied this module successful and now I have 3 Alarms which don't gather data because the CloudWatch Agent wants this last data I guess.
So this Errormessage doesn#t make any sense to me, because I already deployed everything and just my newest apply, after I implemented the ami img id doesn#t work.
I could implement another resource with data in the module where I need it to get rid of this, but I think this is not a good approach when I already retrieved this informations. Sorry that I weren't able to get this question a lil bit shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the output of the wrong module, when you are trying to pass it as input to the "monitoring" module. The output is from module "gitlab". So you need to change your code to this:

```
module "monitoring" {
  ami_img_id = module.gitlab.ami.id
}
```

Comment: Omg how could I overlook this. Thanks a lot! The deployment was successfull but my Alarms remain in the state "Insufficient data" and still I can´t see that they are assigned to a specific Instance. Is there any Attribute I missed in my Cloudwatch resource?

Comment: I changed my code a bit and now the Alarms are assigned to the Instance 
old
```
InstanceId  = data.aws_instance.gitlab_data.instance_id
```
new 
```
InstanceId  = data.aws_instance.gitlab_data.id

```
Somehow instance_id was valid for the syntax, but didn´t work. Still my Alarms are in state "insufficient data" but I guess its not because of the IaC now, maybe.

Comment: @Mark B's answer is totatlly correct, but in addition to that, there is another way to solve it. Rather than having the data resource in the gitlab module you can move it out to the parent in your main or create locals.tf and then pass the output from the data resource as var for both the gitlab and the monitoring module.

Comment: This could be an option. For what purpose is a locals.tf used? I´m not that experienced in Terraform and didn't heard of this. But as I have more and more Data to import to Terraform, I think there is a need to seek an approach to outsource all the imported Data to a specific location.

Comment: If a future reader wants to copy the alarm I have to post changes I made because there were twol other mistakes I made. I simply edit the original post